# what IOS class is represented by a pop up - specifically TabTale's children's apps (lower right)

Tags: ios, button, user-interface, popup

I am coding a new children's story book-apps, want to provide a gui element similar to what Tabtale does on its apps:

- The Three Little Pigs
- Goldilocks and The Three Bears
- Aladdin and The Magic Lamp

the element Im specifically speaking of is in the lower right corner of these (free) apps.
You touch a button once, and a mini menu of items with buttons within presents itself.

This gui doesnt seem to fit Apple's definition of a popover, therefore, Im not sure what it is.

Comment: am told by this site I "need at least 10 reputation" in order to post images... have screenshot ready !

Comment: @MagnaChisel: Try uploading it to imgur and posting a link to that instead.

Comment: http://magnachisel.imgur.com

Comment: so of course what happens is the green button gets pressed and the rest of the "orange" buttons reveal... touch green again and orange disappears.